# Failed Installing Hyperledger Fabric docker images

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, failed-installation, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to install Hyperledger Fabric docker images, but I keep getting the following errors after it downloads the Hyperledger Fabric Binaries.

I'm on a Windows 10 Home edition PC and I have downloaded all the Prerequisites like curl, Docker Toolbox, Go Programming lang and Nodejs & NPM. I have also installed the Visual Studio C++ Build Tools and the NPM GRPC module.

> However, after I ran the `curl -sSL 'url shortened link' | bash -s` command (even the unshortened version), It doesn't seem to download the Hyperledger Fabric docker images. It downloads the samples and the fabric binaries but when it gets to the Hyperledger Fabric docker images, I get the following error. I would appreciate assistance on how to find a solution for this.

````
==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:48694->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:37648->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: ccenv

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:56223->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: tools

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:57861->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: baseos

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:40361->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-baseos:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: nodeenv

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:59697->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:1.4.0
==> FABRIC IMAGE: javaenv

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:36910->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:1.4.0
===> Pulling fabric ca Image
==> FABRIC CA IMAGE

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:41696->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4.2
===> Pulling thirdparty docker images
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: couchdb

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:47343->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.15
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: kafka

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:54708->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka:0.4.15
==> THIRDPARTY DOCKER IMAGE: zookeeper

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:50988->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:0.4.15

===> List out hyperledger docker images```
````

Comment: Docker toolbox for windows has limitations which means you will also have issues with volume mounts unless you adhere to the rules defined by docker toolbox (refer to it's docs for more info). Given the amount of pain required to get this to work on Windows 10 Home I would recommend you use a hypervisor such as virtual box and install a linux distribution and use linux instead.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. However, I decided to just upgrade my Win 10 Home to pro, then downloaded Docker. It has started downloading the images now but it's taking too long, almost 6hrs+. Thanks for the help @david_k

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that you can try

**Method 1**: Uninstall docker and reinstall it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

**Method 2**: Go to `Preferences > Daemon > Advanced`  and set DNS server to 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all docker images first

using

```
$ docker rmi -f $(docker images)
```

After that use each code in terminal one by one

```
sudo apt-get install curl

sudo apt-get install golang-go

export GOPATH=$HOME/go

export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo apt-get install npm

sudo apt-get install python

sudo apt-get install docker

sudo apt-get update

apt-cache policy docker-ce

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

sudo apt-get install docker-compose

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that download samples [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Docker for Windows, in 'system tray', right click on 'Docker' then 'switch to Linux containers'. After this is done, in 'Docker settings', go to [Docker > Settings > Resources > File Sharing] and share 'c drive'. Next in [Docker > Settings > Resources > Proxies] give http and httpsproxy URLS (Example: http://windows-domain-name%5Cwindows-user-name:url-encoded-password@proxy-server-or-ip:proxy-port/).

Also you need 'Virtualization' enabled on Windows 10, not sure if you'll have it in 'Windows 10 home edition', nevertheless you can see it in [Windows Task Manager > Performance Tab > Select CPU on left panel > On the right panel below the graph > you should have virtualization: Enabled]. Also, use 'git bash' to run your commands in Windows. You'll get this when you install 'git' I think.

[image: Windows-task-manager]

[image: Docker-For-Windows-Settings-1]
[image: Docker-For-Windows-Settings-2]